# When you dismiss then call back a familiar does anything it's holding come with it?

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars

So basically lets say I tell my familiar "go pick up my scroll" then after he flies to where my scroll is, can I dismiss him and recall him with the scroll next to me? Or does he simply drop the scroll when he's dismissed?

Comment: This question is similar, but is not an exact duplicate, as it contains an additional factor that the other question does not.  That question is whether you dismiss a familiar locally, and recall it, can it take items into its pocket dimension with it.  This question has the factor of whether you can dismiss a familiar into its pocket dimension remotely, and then recall it locally, thus instantly transporting it, any messages, and whatever it is allowed to carry, from any other location to where you are.

Comment: @PhilBoncer: Yes, but I don't see how that changes things much, except that the existing answers of "only if your DM thinks it's not OP and fits with the world" might shift slightly more toward it being OP. Unless you mean that the question here should simply be revised to ask if dismissing remotely is even possible.

Comment: Well, that would be one of the key factors.  And one that is not addressed in the question this is supposedly a duplicate of.

Comment: @TuggyNE I was assuming a warlock with the voice of the chain master.